# Unable to save calendar data into firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angular5, angular-calendar

I am creating a hall booking feature in my app. In this app, I want to save start date and time and end date and time for a hall booking. When a user books a hall for a full day the date color should be changed.

Here I can get the data from the calendar but it is not being inserted in firebase database. The only data being inserted is the `UID` and `allDay` field. What can I do to fix this?

Here's my code.

```
addEvent() {
  let modal = this.modalCtrl.create('EventModalPage', {
    selectedDay: this.selectedDay
  });
  modal.present();
  modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
    if (data) {
      let eventData = data;
      eventData.startTime = new Date(data.startTime);
      eventData.endTime = new Date(data.endTime);

      let events = [];
      events.push(eventData);
      // this.eventSource = [];
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.eventSource = events;
        console.log(this.eventSource);
        let startTime = this.eventSource['0'].startTime;
        let endTime = this.eventSource['0'].endTime;
        let allDay = this.eventSource['0'].allDay;

        console.log(startTime);
        let currentUserUid = this.fire.auth.currentUser.uid;
        firebase.database().ref('bookingHall/').push({
          uID: currentUserUid,
          startTime: startTime,
          endTime: endTime,
          allDay: allDay,

        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database stores only JSON types. Your `startTime` and `endTime` are JavaScript `Date` objects, which are not valid JSON types. To allow storing dates, either store the timestamp (millisecond since the epoch) or a sortable string representation (`20181101T034027`) of the value.

Also see:

- [Firebase new Date()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382996/firebase-new-date)
- [Firebase Date storage goes wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650212/firebase-date-storage-goes-wrong)
- [Storing date in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855116/storing-date-in-firebase)
- [Storing dates with angular and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957249/storing-dates-with-angular-and-firebase)
- [How do you save a DATE field in Firebase using AngularFire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021133/how-do-you-save-a-date-field-in-firebase-using-angularfire)